# How to resize/adjust the width of a fancybox?

Tags: resize, fancybox, width

I have fancybox that has a width of 800px. It contains a button that redirects to a form when clicked. What I want to do is to resize the width of the fancybox to 400px when I click that button.

Here's the fancybox code for the first fancybox.

```
$("#fancybox-iframe").fancybox().click(function(){
    $.fancybox({
        href : 'user.php',
            type : 'iframe',                        
            scrolling: 'no',
            width: 800px,
            margin: 0,
            padding: [0, 0, 10, 0],
            closeBtn: false
        });
    return false;
});
```

For the form, I did this.

```
<body style="height: 400px; width: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
```

The height works fine but the width is still 800px. How should I do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `$.fancybox.update()`? ... maybe inside a fancybox callback like `afterShow`

Comment: It only works with the height.